# Multithreading table ownership

Tags: java, multithreading

A resource can normally be accessed from multiple threads (the logic for read/write is a little more complex but not the topic of the question). I have to create an method, `owned` , that makes the calling thread the resource's owner and another method, `notOwned`, that makes the resource accessible again for all the threads. So during `owned` the resource can be accesed only by the calling thread, until `notOwned` is called.

```
public class Example {
    public HashMap<String, Stuff> resources;
    public final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    .....

    public void owned(String resource) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        resources.get(resource).lock.lock();
    }

    public void notOwned(String resource) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        resources.get(resource).lock.unlock();      
    }

    public void operation(String resource) {
        //the resource may or may be not owned (it is not owned all the time, as I said)
        boolean own = true;
        while (own) {
            own = ((resources.get(resource).lock.isHeldByCurrentThread() == false) && (resources.get(resource).lock.isLocked()));
        }
        //so now the resource is :
        //1. no longer owned, so all the threads can use it or
        //2. the current thread is the owner
        try {
          //let's consider this operation a writing type
          resources.get(resource).readLock.lock();
          tables.get(resources).information.add(resource);
       }  finally {resources.get(resource).readLock.unlock(); }
    }
```

Waiting for the resource to be no longer locked by a thread is the only solution I came out with... but it is **not** consistent (meaning that I think somehow when the resource is locked, the other threads(so not the owner thread) are still making changes or may not the synchronized correctly ? I do not really know)...It does not have to be ReentrantLock but the logic has to be created around the `owned` and `notOwned` methods.

Comment: That's not how you use locks, the way you're using it doesn't require the `Lock` implementation, it can be a `boolean` value, and of course it won't work. `Lock` guards a `critical section`. Critical section should be between a `Lock.lock()` and `Lock.unlock()` call.

Comment: could you please be more explicit?

Comment: should I change `boolean` to `AtomicBoolean` ? As I said, the logic still needs to be created around `owned` and `notOwned` .

Comment: Please include the code where you're calling `operation()` method, meanwhile I'll try to post an explanation.

Comment: ok, but It doesn't have anything to do with this problem (I think). one moment

Comment: Just want to know how you're utilizing `owned()` and `notOwned()` methods. Is the resource that you're using is exclusively by threads? Or can they be used by multiple threads at a time? Or do you have a number of resources of same time and want them to be locked out only when all the resources are in use

Comment: they are used exclusively, by multiple threads at a time.

Comment: i updated the method's content

Comment: anyone. please? a hint could be just as good :)

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java a thread goes in waiting state when it tries to acquire a monitor (Internal lock object) on an object whose monitor is not available (is already locked). Once this monitor is unlocked, all the threads waiting on this monitor object are notified. These threads complete for the monitor and one of the threads will again acquire the monitor and others will go to WAIT state.

Please take a look at the following sample based on your code, this is the correct way of using locks.

```
public class Stuff {
    public final ReentrantLock resourceLock = new ReentrantLock();

    public void doStuff() {

        /*Once locked by one thread other threads would be waiting on this line in WAIT state
         * There's no need to check if it's already locked or not, it's done by Java, if it's locked then Thread goes in WAIT state
         * It's not busy waiting, thread wakes up only when notified by Java.
         */
        resourceLock.lock();
        try {
            /* <Critical Section> */
            //Now since resource is locked, it can be exclusively used by this thread

            /* </Critical Section> */
        } finally {
            //Once unlocked other threads would compete to acquire lock on: resourceLock.lock();
            resourceLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

public class Example {
    public HashMap<String, Stuff> resources;

    /**
     * This is a utility method to just check if the resource is locked by current Thread, it performs no role in locking resource.
     */
    public boolean isOwned(String resource) {
        return ((resources.get(resource).lock.isHeldByCurrentThread() == false) && (resources.get(resource).lock.isLocked()))
    }

    public boolean isNotOwned(String resource) {
        return !isOwned();
    }

    public void operation(String resource) {
        Stuff stuff = resources.get(resource);
        stuff.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Some interesting things about WAIT state

1. A thread in waiting state has to relinquish all the monitors held by it. That means even if it has bee notified for one monitor it will have to compete for all the monitors that it was using again.
2. It's not busy waiting like checking lock state in loop.

**Edit: With temporary critical section, may be set parallel or non parallel dynamically**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class Stuff {
    public final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    public AtomicBoolean isParallel = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    public AtomicInteger currentlyRunningThreadCount = new AtomicInteger();
    public CountDownLatch latch;

    public final static int MAX_WAIT_IN_SECONDS = 20;

    public void doStuff() throws Exception {

        if( !isParallel.get()) {
            System.out.println(threadName() + " Waiting");

            synchronized(this) {
                if(latch == null) {
                    latch = new CountDownLatch(currentlyRunningThreadCount.get());/*Excluding the current thread with -1*/
                    System.out.println("latch count : " + latch.getCount() + " " + latch);
                }
            }
            latch.await(MAX_WAIT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            if( !lock.tryLock(MAX_WAIT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                throw new Exception("Could not acquire lock in specified time");
            }

            currentlyRunningThreadCount.incrementAndGet();

            System.out.println(threadName() + " Woke up");
        }

        try {
            /* <Critical Section> */
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                System.out.println(threadName() + " \tRunning");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            /* </Critical Section> */
        } finally {

            if(currentlyRunningThreadCount.get() > 0) {
                currentlyRunningThreadCount.decrementAndGet();
            }
            if( !isParallel.get() && latch != null) {
                latch.countDown();
                System.out.println(threadName() + " down latch " + latch.getCount() + " " + latch);
            }

            if(lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        System.out.println(threadName() + " Done do stuff");
    }

    public boolean isParallel() {
        return isParallel.get();
    }

    public void setParallel(boolean newValue) throws Exception {
        synchronized(this) {
            if(latch != null) {
                latch.await();
            }

            latch = null;
        }

        isParallel.set(newValue);
    }

    public String threadName() {
        return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }
}

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Started");
        Stuff stuff = new Stuff();

        Runnable run = () -> {
            try {
                stuff.doStuff();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        Thread t1 = new Thread(null, run, "t1");
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(null, run, "t2");
        t2.start();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        stuff.setParallel(false);
        Thread t5 = new Thread(null, run, "t5");
        t5.start();

        Thread t6 = new Thread(null, run, "t6");
        t6.start();

        System.out.println("##### main exiting");
    }
}

Started
t1  Running
t2  Running
t1  Running
t2  Running
t5 Waiting
latch count : 0 java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@61e7093d[Count = 0]
##### main exiting
t6 Waiting
t5 Woke up
t5  Running
t2  Running
t1  Running
t5  Running
t2 down latch 0 java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@61e7093d[Count = 0]
t2 Done do stuff
t1 down latch 0 java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@61e7093d[Count = 0]
t1 Done do stuff
t5  Running
t5 down latch 0 java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@61e7093d[Count = 0]
t5 Done do stuff
t6 Woke up
t6  Running
t6  Running
t6  Running
t6 down latch 0 java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@61e7093d[Count = 0]
t6 Done do stuff
```

Comment: the thing is that the method `doStuff` should be done parallel by all the threads until `isOwned` is called, I think that with this approach only one thread at a time can access the critical section.

Comment: That's a unique use case. What happens to the threads that're still running `doStuff()` when it's marked non parallel?

Comment: they wait until `isNotOwned` is called, then do their job

Comment: That's not possible, as that would mean you would have to check for the `doStuff()` state after running evey statement.

Comment: i'll try to use a semaphore approach

Comment: I think it can be done if we just let the executing threads finish the `doStuff()` execution before marking `doStuff()` parallel.

Comment: I just added a sample that's closer to your use case.